# ReNaming files with python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I've beem browsing through some older questions and looking for a way to rename files that load into a folder.

So far I've got a folder which gets loaded with files some times per day a few files.

First of all I want to move all these files from lets say 'C:\Folder' to 'F:\Folder1'.

After I've moved the files I want to rename them using a python script. So far I've been looking at something like the below.

```
import os, sys
print "Current directory is: %s" %os.getcwd()

# listing directories
print "The dir is: %s"%os.listdir(os.getcwd())

# renaming file "aa1.txt"
os.renames("aa1.txt","newdir/aanew.txt")

print "Successfully renamed."
```

But I want to loop it so that all files get their names changed. Example MyFile1.csv if there are more MyFile2, MyFile3 etc

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225735/batch-renaming-of-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Check that link maybe it can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to reference the answers to this question: [How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207219/483917) on stackoverflow. In a nutshell, os.listdir or walk will do the trick to get you a list of file names. Then, you can rename them at will.

Three snippets from the referenced document: [How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207219/483917)

```
os.listdir("somedirectory")

filenames = next(os.walk(path))[2]

# Return everything under C:\Users\admin that contains a folder called wlp.
from glob import glob
glob('C:\Users\admin\*\wlp')
```

instead of simply polling a dir, here are some tools to check if a windows dir has modifications you may want to act upon:

- Watchdog: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog
- QFileSystemWatcher: (*ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339877/483917)

I'm mostly a linux user, so for any linux users out there, you may also want to look at `inotify` *(which, despite some other comments I've read about it, worked just fine for me)*:

- pyinotify: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

I hope that helps.