# Rename file names in a folder - Python

Tags: python

I have files in a folder. Their names look like:

```
hello_1
music
hello_2
music_2015
```

I would like to rename them sequentially:

```
1
2
3
4
```

My python script is:

```
import glob, os

n = 1
for filename in glob.glob('data\*'):
    os.rename(filename, str(n))
    n += 1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

Comment: Is there a file named "1" in that folder already?

Comment: No, but some names include the number "1" such as pm_11_1.txt

Comment: I'll reiterate - is there *any* file that is just a number (like "1" or "5" or what have you)? Because the error clearly says that you're trying to rename a file into a name of an already existing file.

Comment: no he is in the parent folder ,... he probably ran it part way and has already renamed some of the files to numbers

Comment: how will you decide which name to give to which file? Is there any specific order we need to rename them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file renaming using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075818/file-renaming-using-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Renaming of Files in a Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225735/batch-renaming-of-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this version:

```
import os
data = os.path.abspath("data/")
for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir(data)):
    src = os.path.join(data, f)
    dst = os.path.join(data, (str(i + 1)))
    os.rename(src, dst)
```

It's using normalized absolute paths. It works for me. It's kind of more concise and requires only `os` library instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

That script rename that files and change their location to the parent folder, in this case, parent of the data folder. Maybe you have some file with these number in the parent folder. You should attach the folder name to the rename function's second parameter.

Comment: he should really create a temp folder first to ensure no collisions ... but meh

Comment: Thanks. See my revised script below.

Comment: You should find the last '\' character in the filename. Like this: `directory = filename[:filename.rfind('\')+1]` and then rename like this : `os.rename(filename, directory + str(n))`

Answer (score 2):

> os.rename(src, dst)
>
> Rename the file or directory src to dst. If dst is a directory, OSError will be raised. On Unix, if dst exists and is a file, it will be replaced silently if the user has permission. The operation may fail on some Unix flavors if src and dst are on different filesystems. If successful, the renaming will be an atomic operation (this is a POSIX requirement). On Windows, if dst already exists, OSError will be raised even if it is a file; there may be no way to implement an atomic rename when dst names an existing file.

Your destination is wrong. It is your current directory + `n` while it should be the `data` directory + `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script `rename_files.py`. you should place this script inside the folder where all your `files` are located.

Also note:

> os.rename(src, dst)
>
> Rename the file or directory src to dst. If dst is a directory,
>   OSError will be raised. On Unix, if dst exists and is a file, it will
>   be replaced silently if the user has permission. The operation may
>   fail on some Unix flavors if src and dst are on different filesystems.
>   If successful, the renaming will be an atomic operation (this is a
>   POSIX requirement). On Windows, if dst already exists, OSError will be
>   raised even if it is a file; there may be no way to implement an atomic rename when dst names an existing file.

```
import os

list_of_files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

n = 1
for filename in list_of_files:
    if not filename.endswith(".py"):
        os.rename(filename, str(n))
        n += 1
```

Before running this script you can see the `file_names` and `directory`.
[image]

After running this script. I hope this is helpful
[image]

Comment: why not `if not filename.endswith(".py"): os.rename(filename, str(n))` and forget the pass?