# Python - rename files incrementally based on julian day

Tags: python, glob

**Problem:**
I have a bunch of files that were downloaded from an org. Halfway through their data directory the org changed the naming convention (reasons unknown). I am looking to create a script that will take the files in a directory and rename the file the same way, but simply "go back one day".

Here is a sample of how one file is named: `org2015365_res_version.asc`

What I need is logic to only change the year day (`2015365`) in this case to `2015364`. This logic needs to span a few years so `2015001` would be `2014365`.

I guess I'm not sure this is possible since its not working with the current date so using a module like `datetime` does not seem applicable.

Partial logic I came up with. I know it is rudimentary at best, but wanted to take a stab at it.

```
# open all files
all_data = glob.glob('/somedir/org*.asc')

# empty array to be appended to
day = []
year = []

# loop through all files
for f in all_data:
    # get first part of string, renders org2015365
    f_split = f.split('_')[0]
    # get only year day - renders 2015365
    year_day = f_split.replace(f_split[:3], '')
    # get only day - renders 365
    days = year_day.replace(year_day[0:4], '')
    # get only year - renders 2015
    day.append(days)
    years = year_day.replace(year_day[4:], '')
    year.append(years)
    # convert to int for easier processing 
    day = [int(i) for i in day]
    year = [int(i) for i in year]

    if day == 001 & year == 2016:
        day = 365
        year = 2015
    elif day == 001 & year == 2015:
        day = 365
        year = 2014
    else:
        day = day - 1
```

Apart from the logic above I also came across the function below from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225735/batch-renaming-of-files-in-a-directory) post, I am not sure what would be the best way to combine that with the partial logic above. Thoughts?

```
import glob
import os


def rename(dir, pattern, titlePattern):
    for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, pattern)):
        title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
        os.rename(pathAndFilename,
                  os.path.join(dir, titlePattern % title + ext))

rename(r'c:\temp\xx', r'*.doc', r'new(%s)')
```

Help me, stackoverflow. You're my only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html) module:

```
#First argument - string like 2015365, second argument - format
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(year_day,'%Y%j')
#Time shift
dt = dt + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
#Year with shift
nyear = dt.year
#Day in year with shift
nday = dt.timetuple().tm_yday
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback from the community I was able to get the logic needed to fix the files downloaded from the org! The logic was the biggest hurdle. It turns out that the `datetime` module can be used, I need to read up more on that.

I combined the logic with the batch renaming using the `os` module, I put the code below to help future users who may have a similar question!

```
# open all files
all_data = glob.glob('/some_dir/org*.asc')

# loop through
for f in all_data:
    # get first part of string, renders org2015365
    f_split = f.split('_')[1]
    # get only year day - renders 2015365
    year_day = f_split.replace(f_split[:10], '')
    # first argument - string 2015365, second argument - format the string to datetime
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(year_day, '%Y%j')
    # create a threshold where version changes its naming convention
    # only rename files greater than threshold
    threshold = '2014336'
    th = datetime.datetime.strptime(threshold, '%Y%j')
    if dt > th:
        # Time shift - go back one day
        dt = dt + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
        # Year with shift
        nyear = dt.year
        # Day in year with shift
        nday = dt.timetuple().tm_yday
        # rename files correctly
        f_output = 'org' + str(nyear) + str(nday).zfill(3) + '_res_version.asc'
        os.rename(f, '/some_dir/' + f_output)
    else:
        pass
```