# Python- Replace all spaces with underscores and convert to lowercase for all files in a directory

Tags: python

I am trying to do as the title explains, but am given the message
 WinError2: cannot find the file specified 'New Text Document.txt' -> 'new_text_document.txt' with the code snippet below. Yes, my Desktop is on drive letter D, and this assumes the target directory is named 'directory'. I have a sample file in the directory named 'New Text Document.txt'. I just can't figure out where the problem is.

```
import os
path = 'D:\Desktop\directory'
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, filename.replace(' ', '_').lower())
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A one-liner using list comprehension:

```
import os

directory = 'D:\Desktop\directory'

[os.rename(os.path.join(directory, f), os.path.join(directory, f).replace(' ', '_').lower()) for f in os.listdir(directory)]
```

list-comprehension borrowed from answer [Batch Renaming of Files in a Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7917798/1248974)

Comment: Brilliant, though i must admit that's a little hard to follow for a novice like me. Could you explain what f is doing?

Comment: Sure! Sorry about the confusion, `f` is just a variable name for each file in the directory that is getting renamed. So in plain speak it would be for each `f in os.listdir(directory)` ("for each file in the directory"). Of course, feel free to use change/ use other variable names, being consistent with renaming all of them, and use variable names that are easy to understand.

Comment: This code is *almost identical* to the code in lsalamon's answer, which his answer probably is easier to read (for each...do this), and `f` in my example would be the same variable as `filename` in lsalamon's answer.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Things are starting to make sense. I wound up using something very similar to you and isalamon's answers, just formatted in a way to help me read it. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Great, glad to hear you got something working that makes sense for you, good luck. Cheers!

Comment: It should be `os.path.join(directory, f.replace(' ', '_').lower()))` if you want to replace only the base file name and not the folder names too.

Answer (score 7):

use the full file naming for safer os operations:

```
import os
path = 'D:\\test'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    #print(filename)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename),os.path.join(path, filename.replace(' ', '_').lower()))
```

Comment: How is using string concatenation *safer os operation*? It would be better to use `os.path.join` or move on to use `pathlib.Path` altogether

Comment: brilliant, clear answer.

Comment: if you want to do multiple replaces of different characters, simply duplicate the `os.rename` line and change the replace parameters with new characters.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method using os.walk(directory) if you want to do this recursively through several levels of folders:

```
import os

directory = r'D:\Desktop\directory'

# Use underscore? Otherwise defaults to hyphen
is_use_underscore = True
char_to_use = '_' if is_use_underscore else '-'   

print("Renaming files now!")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    print(f"root: {root}")
    print(f"dirs: {dirs}")
    print(f"files: {files}")

    for current_filename in files:
        new_filename = current_filename.replace(' ', char_to_use)

        print(f"current filename: {current_filename}")
        print(f"    new filename: {new_filename}")

        os.rename(
            os.path.join(root, current_filename), 
            os.path.join(root, new_filename)
        )   

print("All done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not specify the directory where the New Text Document.txt is for the os.rename function. You can just add this line before the for loop.

```
os.chdir(path)
```

And either use raw strings or full file paths, because the way you defined path will also give you an error.

`path = r'D:\Desktop\directory`' or `path = 'D:\\Desktop\\directory'`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. Is D:\Desktop\directory not a full file path?

Comment: @Gl0rph If you use path='"C:\Desktop\directory"' the \ will act as an escape character. So it wont give you the expected result. That's why you should use two backslashes '\\' to cancel that escape character. or use any other way as mentioned, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/2998262)

Comment: Ohhh wow, that's a huge help! Thank you Sherif, that explains why a few other scripts I've been playing around with aren't working right...

Comment: @Gl0rph No problem! Am glad to help.