# How can i rename my images?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder of images, they have random names. What i want to do is change the images names to numbers for example 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg and so on till the images are done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename files sequentially in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286364/rename-files-sequentially-in-python)

Comment: You can do it in bash: `paste <(ls) <(for i in $(seq $(ls -1 | wc -l)); do echo $i.jpg; done) | xargs -l mv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is `os.listdir()` to list all items in a folder and `os.rename` to rename those items.

```
import os

contents = os.listdir()

for i, filename in enumerate(contents):
    os.rename(filename, i) # or i.jpg or whatever which is beyond that scope
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = '/Path/To/Directory'
files = os.listdir(path)
i = 1


for file in files:
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, str(i)+'.jpg'))
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `os` library:

If the folder has images only, no other files, you can run in the correct folder:

```
import os
count = 1
for picture in os.listdir():
    os.rename(picture, f'{count}.jpg')
    count += 1
```

You can read more about `os` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html