# System cannot find the file specified when renaming image files

Tags: python, image-processing, sequence, file-rename

I have more than 1000 JPG images in a folder having different name. I want to rename images as 0.JPG, 1.jpg, 2.jpg...

I tried different code but having below error:

`The system cannot find the file specified: 'IMG_0102.JPG' -> '1.JPG'`

The below code is one the codes found in this link: [Rename files sequentially in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286364/rename-files-sequentially-in-python)

```
import os
_src = "C:\\Users\\sazid\\Desktop\\snake"
_ext = ".JPG"
for i,filename in enumerate(os.listdir(_src)):
    if filename.endswith(_ext):
        os.rename(filename, str(i)+_ext)
```

How to solve this error. Any better code to rename image files in sequential order?

Comment: In `os.rename(filename,...` it's looking for the filename in the working directory (the directory you're running the script in). Change that part to `os.rename(os.getcwd() + filename,...`

Comment: @SazidaBintaIslam if you found a solution mark the correct answer or close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `glob` and save yourself the headache

with glob your code turns into this:

```py
import os
from glob import glob

target_dir = './some/dir/with/data'

for i, p in enumerate(glob(f'{target_dir}/*.jpg')):
    os.rename(p, f'{target_dir}/{i}.jpg')
```

in this code `glob()` gives you a list of found file paths for files that have the `.jpg` extension, hence the `*.jpg` pattern for `glob`, [here is more on `glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Comment: @SazidaBintaIslam mark it as the answer then maybe.. ?

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir` only returns the filenames, it doesn't include the directory name. You'll need to include that when renaming. Try something like this:

```
import os
_src = "C:\\Users\\sazid\\Desktop\\snake"
_ext = ".JPG"
for i,filename in enumerate(os.listdir(_src)):
    if filename.endswith(_ext):
        src_file = os.path.join(_src, filename)
        dst_file = os.path.join(_src, str(i)+_ext)
        os.rename(src_file, dst_file)
```

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot. 
but it started from 1.JPG, it couldn't start from 0.JPG. Interestingly, one image didn't rename. 
though it's fine for me but wanted to know why is like that.

Comment: @SazidaBintaIslam that sounds like a new question.