# Python: how to rename a file in a folder?

Tags: python, rename, file-rename

I have a list of file like the following

```
'TRIAL_20134_75690_TOTAL_2018-08-12-17-18.csv'
```

I want to rename them the parte after the last underscore, such as the file will be renamed like:

```
'TRIAL_20134_75690_TOTAL.csv'
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225735/batch-renaming-of-files-in-a-directory

Comment: The [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) modules in the standard library have functions that do this sort of thing.  It's worth checking out if there's something helpful [in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) _before_ asking SO.

Comment: @DavidMaze I not everyone has the same philosophy as me, but in the time it took you to write the comment, I just got the guy on his way. :p

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.rename` from the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) library to do the renaming.

To get the sting up to the last index of an underscore (`_`), use the `rindex` method of `string`.

You also need to concatenate the extension back on.

I.e.

```
import os
f = 'TRIAL_20134_75690_TOTAL_2018-08-12-17-18.csv'
os.rename(f, f[:f.rindex('_'] + '.csv')
```