# How to change all file names in folder?

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains about 300 CSV files that have different names. I want to change all the file name to some new names:

my input files:

```
newAdress.csv
yourInformation.csv
countatnt.csv
.
.
```

I checked a few posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225735/batch-renaming-of-files-in-a-directory) but it's not saving in the format I want.

I tried to do as :

```
import glob, os
def rename(dir, pattern, titlePattern):
    print('pattern', pattern)
    for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, pattern)):
        title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
        os.rename(pathAndFilename, 
                  os.path.join(dir, titlePattern % title + ext))
```

And then:

```
rename(r'/Users/Documnet/test', r'*.csv', r'file(%s)')
```

And i got:

```
file(newAdress).csv
file(yourInformation).csv
.
```

but it i need to save in the format of (`newAdress.csv -> file1.csv`, `yourInformation.csv -> file2.csv`):

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
.
.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean/22171593

Comment: I think i need to add something like {i} at the end of ```file(%s)..```which enumerates from ```1``` to ```length of the folder``` but i am not sure how to do ir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your for loop to something like this:

```
for n, pathAndFilename in enumerate(glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, pattern))):
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
    os.rename(pathAndFilename, os.path.join(dir, titlePattern.format(n+1)) + ext)
```

But also you should call your function as (remove the parentheses):

```
rename(r'/Users/Documnet/test', r'*.csv', r'file{}')
```

Note I also changed the syntax since `str.format` is favored over the `%` syntax.